# Creative Commons license is disabled

Tags: youtube

How can I enable the Creative Commons license for a video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are allowed to mark it as CC.

> **Things you should know**
>
> The ability to mark uploaded videos with a Creative Commons license is only available to users whose account is in good standing. You may check the status of your account under the [Manage Account](http://www.youtube.com/account?feature=mhum#manage/status) section of your Account Settings.

From here: http://www.youtube.com/t/creative_commons

Also,

> You cannot mark your video with the Creative Commons license if there is a claim on it.

From here: http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1284989